# librd Kafka config settings for kerberos authentication

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, librdkafka

My target cluster is kerberos enabled. From the console, the producer connection is working.

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list targetHost:port --topic test --producer.config /path/to/client.properties
```

I have added below entry in my bash_profile to pass jaas.conf and krb5.conf

```
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/jaas.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/path/to/krb5.conf"
```

Here is the client.properties settings.

> security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
>
> sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka

I am using `librdkafka` to produce the messages to Kafka and configured `security.protocol` and `sasl.kerberos.service.name` for kafka `configmap` object.  But the connection is not happening.

How do I integrate `jaas.conf` and `krb5.conf` through GoLang.

Error:

> [thrd:sasl_plaintext://targetHost:port/bootstrap]:
> sasl_plaintext://targetHost:port/bootstrap: Failed to initialize SASL
> authentication: SASL handshake failed (start (-1)): SASL(-1): generic
> failure: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text (Server
> (kafka/targetHost) unknown while looking up 'targetHost' (cached
> result, timeout in 128 sec)

Comment: What is the error and what is the content of `client.properties`?

Comment: Updated the details.

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved after adding the below environment variable.

> export KRB5_CONFIG="/path/to/krb5.conf

Additionally added the below kafka config option

```
sasl.kerberos.keytab: /path/to/keytab/file.keytab
```